# Formatting DateCell Backgrid js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I am using the Backgrid js component for showing my data grid. It's pretty straightforward and simple.

However I am having difficulties formatting the date to show up in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy it shows up in yyyy/mm/dd format by default.

Can anyone provide examples on how to format this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the moment-cell extension.

http://backgridjs.com/#api-moment-cell

Comment: Thanks a ton. Should have seen that earlier on the site.